# How do I use Jenkins to build a private GitHub Rust project with a private GitHub dependency?

Tags: jenkins, github, rust

I have a private GitHub Rust project that depends on another private GitHub Rust project and I want to build the main one with Jenkins. I have called the organization `Organization` and the dependency package `subcrate` in the below code.

My Jenkinsfile looks something like

```
pipeline {
  agent {
    docker {
      image 'rust:latest'
    }
  }

  stages {

    stage('Build') {
      steps {
        sh "cargo build"
      }
    }

    etc...

  }
}
```

I have tried the following in `Cargo.toml` to reference the dependency, it works fine on my machine

```
[dependencies]
subcrate = { git = "ssh://git@ssh.github.com/Organization/subcrate.git", tag = "0.1.0" }
```

When Jenkins runs I get the following error

```
+ cargo build

    Updating registry `https://github.com/rust-lang/crates.io-index`

    Updating git repository `ssh://git@github.com/Organization/subcrate.git`

error: failed to load source for a dependency on `subcrate`

Caused by:

  Unable to update ssh://git@github.com/Organization/subcrate.git?tag=0.1.0#0623c097

Caused by:

  failed to clone into: /usr/local/cargo/git/db/subcrate-3e391025a927594e

Caused by:

  failed to authenticate when downloading repository

attempted ssh-agent authentication, but none of the usernames `git` succeeded

Caused by:

  error authenticating: no auth sock variable; class=Ssh (23)

script returned exit code 101
```

How can I get Cargo to access this GitHub repository? Do I need to inject the GitHub credentials onto the slave? If so, how can I do this? Is it possible to use the same credentials Jenkins uses to checkout the main crate in the first place?

I installed the `ssh-agent` plugin and updated my Jenkinsfile to look like this

```
pipeline {
  agent {
    docker {
      image 'rust:latest'
    }
  }

  stages {
    stage('Build') {
      steps {
        sshagent(credentials: ['id-of-github-credentials']) {
          sh "ssh -vvv -T git@github.com"
          sh "cargo build"
        }
      }
    }

    etc...

  }
}
```

I get the error

```
+ ssh -vvv -T git@github.com

No user exists for uid 113

script returned exit code 255
```

Comment: You can use `ssh-agent`

Comment: I assume you are referring to this plugin https://plugins.jenkins.io/ssh-agent will this add the credentials to the docker slave?

Comment: I did not think about a precise plugin, but if you can add the ssh key somehow, everything should be fine.

Comment: I tried with ssh-agent plugin, getting a different error now, any tips? (see the edit)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, I figured it out, `No user exists for uid` error is because of a mismatch between the users in the host `/etc/passwd` and the container `/etc/passwd`. This can be fixed by mounting `/etc/passwd`.

```
  agent {
    docker {
      image 'rust:latest'
      args '-v /etc/passwd:/etc/passwd'
    }
  }
```

Then

```
  sshagent(credentials: ['id-of-github-credentials']) {
    sh "cargo build"
  }
```

Works just fine